# Is there a global form error component in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple Angular 4 form, using Angular Material (beta23). I understand that I can add individual mat-error to input fields. However, I'm looking for a "global" alert, similar to a Bootstrap alert. Ideally, it would be:

- Place at the top of the form
- Dismissible with a close "X"
- Have an attribute to distinguish between warning and error

Regarding the "but error messages should be placed next to the offending entry" ... I need to global component for server-side errors from eg. optimistic locking ("Data on this form has been changed in the meantime. Submit again to overwrite, or refresh"), multi-control validation errors ("A customer with identical name has already been registered for the same address.")

Thanks, Simon

Comment: Short answer is No. There is no global form error component in material 2. You can create your own component for that purpose using existing material components.

Comment: There is no perfect solution in Material right now, but I see two options
1. use Snackbar
2. use mat-error right below submit button

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll create a custom error component

Answer (score 0):

We've created a custom component, code is listed on our [blog](https://funneltravel.wordpress.com/2017/11/03/create-a-global-error-component-for-angular-4/).